# Tensorflow LSTM: poor performance of the multivariate model compared to the univariate and analyzing the Influence of variables on the target var

Tags: python, tensorflow, neural-network

I'm building two LSTM using Tensorflow:

1 - Univariate: Time series with only the target variable

2 -Multivariate: Time series with several other variables, including the target.

However, the multivariate model, contrary to what I thought, does not perform better than the univariate one.

**Question 1:** Can this be explained by the fact that the variables used in the multivariate model have low and very low correlation?

Therefore, I thought it would be interesting to analyze the Influence of the various variables on the target variable.

I tried to use this code, but it doesn't return what I'm looking for.

```
model.trainable_variables
```

**Question 2:** Is it possible to verify on tensorflow how the weights of the variables intervene in the construction of the ANN by identifying the input variables that have a greater impact on the result? Something similar that happens with the [method of Garson](https://www.researchgate.net/post/Garson-algorithm-in-ANN)